# Почему результат равен undefined?

Tags: javascript

Получите произведение всех чисел в массиве, используя ***`Array.reduce`***. Не обрабатывайте типы данных, не являющиеся числом.

```js
let array = ["0", 5, 3, "string", null];
let mult = array.reduce((sum, current) => {
  if (typeof(current) == "number") {
    return sum *= current;
  }
}, 1)
console.log(mult);
```

Comment: а если не является числом, что у вас возвращает анонимная стрелочная функция?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка происходила из-за того, что при значении не числового типа, функция переданная в reduce не возвращала значения явно (а значит возвращала undefined по умолчанию)

```js
let array = ["0", 5, 3, "string", null];
let mult = array.reduce((sum, current) => 
  typeof(current) === "number" ? sum * current: sum, 1
)
console.log(mult);
```